# How create async callback function in v8 C++ (not using Node JS)?

Tags: c++, v8

I tried to create a callback in v8 js engine but that does not work. That is, I can not save the function in order to call it later. Look the floor Google, but there everything is written about how to do it through Node JS. AAnd how to do without Node JS on a clean V8 ? PS: Under the callback I will enter this:

```
function Func()
{
    print("YEEES");
}
cl.register(Func);
```

Tried to save like this (but this not work):

```
v8::Persistent<v8::Function> *savedFunc = NULL;
Locker locker(_isolate);
HandleScope scope(_isolate);
Handle<Function> args1 = Handle<Function>::Cast(args[0]);

savedFunc = new v8::Persistent<v8::Function>();
savedFunc->Reset(_isolate, args1);
```

I need this to describe the actions of the program on JS. That is, for example, add an event of pressing a button or movement with the mouse and call it from C ++. (This is what I do for the game)

Please, sorry for my English.
The google translate

---

### EDIT

Thanks to pinepain for the answer

Solution of the problem:
CPP

```
//callback test
//Рабочий пример каллбека. В коде много лишнего
//Working example of callback. Here a lot of things you can delete
#include <include/v8.h>

#include <include/libplatform/libplatform.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <map>
#include <process.h>
#include <string>

using std::map;
using std::pair;
using std::string;

using v8::Context;
using v8::EscapableHandleScope;
using v8::External;
using v8::Function;
using v8::FunctionTemplate;
using v8::Global;
using v8::HandleScope;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::MaybeLocal;
using v8::Name;
using v8::NamedPropertyHandlerConfiguration;
using v8::NewStringType;
using v8::Object;
using v8::ObjectTemplate;
using v8::PropertyCallbackInfo;
using v8::Script;
using v8::String;
using v8::TryCatch;
using v8::Value;

class HttpRequestProcessor {
public:
    virtual ~HttpRequestProcessor() { }
    virtual bool Initialize(map<string, string>* options,map<string, string>* output) = 0;
    virtual bool Process() = 0;
    static void Log(const char* event);
};

class JsHttpRequestProcessor : public HttpRequestProcessor {
public:
    JsHttpRequestProcessor(Isolate* isolate, Local<String> script)
        : isolate_(isolate), script_(script) {}
    virtual ~JsHttpRequestProcessor();
    virtual bool Initialize(map<string, string>* opts,      map<string, string>* output);
    virtual bool Process();

private:
    bool ExecuteScript(Local<String> script);
    Isolate* GetIsolate() { return isolate_; }

    Isolate* isolate_;
    Local<String> script_;
    Global<Context> context_;
    Global<Function> process_;
};
Global<Function> process_f;

static void LogCallback(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
    if (args.Length() < 1) return;
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);
    Local<Value> arg = args[0];
    String::Utf8Value value(isolate, arg);
    HttpRequestProcessor::Log(*value);
}

static void Callback(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) {
    if (args.Length() < 1) return;
    Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);
    Local<Value> arg = args[0];
    if (!arg->IsFunction()) {
        return;
    }
    Local<Function> process_fun = Local<Function>::Cast(arg);
    process_f.Reset(isolate, process_fun);
}

bool JsHttpRequestProcessor::Initialize(map<string, string>* opts,
    map<string, string>* output) {
    HandleScope handle_scope(GetIsolate());

    Local<ObjectTemplate> global = ObjectTemplate::New(GetIsolate());
    global->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(GetIsolate(), "log", NewStringType::kNormal)
        .ToLocalChecked(),
        FunctionTemplate::New(GetIsolate(), LogCallback));
    global->Set(String::NewFromUtf8(GetIsolate(), "callback", NewStringType::kNormal)
        .ToLocalChecked(),
        FunctionTemplate::New(GetIsolate(), Callback));

    v8::Local<v8::Context> context = Context::New(GetIsolate(), NULL, global);
    context_.Reset(GetIsolate(), context);

    Context::Scope context_scope(context);

    if (!ExecuteScript(script_))
        return false;

    Local<String> process_name =
        String::NewFromUtf8(GetIsolate(), "Process", NewStringType::kNormal)
        .ToLocalChecked();
    Local<Value> process_val;
    if (!context->Global()->Get(context, process_name).ToLocal(&process_val) ||
        !process_val->IsFunction()) {
        return false;
    }
    Local<Function> process_fun = Local<Function>::Cast(process_val);
    process_.Reset(GetIsolate(), process_fun);
    return true;
}


bool JsHttpRequestProcessor::ExecuteScript(Local<String> script) {
    HandleScope handle_scope(GetIsolate());

    TryCatch try_catch(GetIsolate());

    Local<Context> context(GetIsolate()->GetCurrentContext());

    Local<Script> compiled_script;
    if (!Script::Compile(context, script).ToLocal(&compiled_script)) {
        String::Utf8Value error(GetIsolate(), try_catch.Exception());
        Log(*error);
        return false;
    }

    Local<Value> result;
    if (!compiled_script->Run(context).ToLocal(&result)) {
        String::Utf8Value error(GetIsolate(), try_catch.Exception());
        Log(*error);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


bool JsHttpRequestProcessor::Process() {
    HandleScope handle_scope(GetIsolate());

    v8::Local<v8::Context> context =
        v8::Local<v8::Context>::New(GetIsolate(), context_);
    Context::Scope context_scope(context);

    TryCatch try_catch(GetIsolate());
    v8::Local<v8::Function> process =
        v8::Local<v8::Function>::New(GetIsolate(), process_f);
    Local<Value> result;
    if (!process->Call(context, context->Global(), 0, {}).ToLocal(&result)) {
        String::Utf8Value error(GetIsolate(), try_catch.Exception());
        Log(*error);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


JsHttpRequestProcessor::~JsHttpRequestProcessor() {
    context_.Reset();
    process_.Reset();
}

void HttpRequestProcessor::Log(const char* event) {
    printf("Logged: %s\n", event);
}


void ParseOptions(int argc,
    char* argv[],
    map<string, string>* options,
    string* file) {
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        string arg = argv[i];
        size_t index = arg.find('=', 0);
        if (index == string::npos) {
            *file = arg;
        }
        else {
            string key = arg.substr(0, index);
            string value = arg.substr(index + 1);
            (*options)[key] = value;
        }
    }
}


// Reads a file into a v8 string.
MaybeLocal<String> ReadFile(Isolate* isolate, const string& name) {
    FILE* file = fopen(name.c_str(), "rb");
    if (file == NULL) return MaybeLocal<String>();

    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    size_t size = ftell(file);
    rewind(file);

    char* chars = new char[size + 1];
    chars[size] = '\0';
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size;) {
        i += fread(&chars[i], 1, size - i, file);
        if (ferror(file)) {
            fclose(file);
            return MaybeLocal<String>();
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    MaybeLocal<String> result = String::NewFromUtf8(
        isolate, chars, NewStringType::kNormal, static_cast<int>(size));
    delete[] chars;
    return result;
}
JsHttpRequestProcessor* proc;
void cproc() 
{
    proc->Process();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
    v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
    std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
    v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
    v8::V8::Initialize();
    map<string, string> options;
    string file;
    ParseOptions(argc, argv, &options, &file);
    if (file.empty()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "No script was specified.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
    create_params.array_buffer_allocator =
        v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::New(create_params);
    Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);
    HandleScope scope(isolate);
    Local<String> source;
    if (!ReadFile(isolate, file).ToLocal(&source)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error reading '%s'.\n", file.c_str());
        return 1;
    }
    proc = new JsHttpRequestProcessor(isolate, source);
    map<string, string> output;
    if (!proc->Initialize(&options, &output)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing processor.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while (true)
        {
            cproc();
        }
    }
```

JS

```
function proc()
{
    log("Print: " + a);
    a++;
}
callback(proc);
```

Original code (github): [process.cc](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/ffee558e14e28fc8b1f9a3c10ea3615e0d686c7b/samples/process.cc)

Comment: Hi! To make it short, give a look to the v8 samples, especially to [shell.cc](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/samples/shell.cc). Also, give a look at [test-api.cc](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/test/cctest/test-api.cc) which contains vast majority v8 use cases and it may give you a perspective where to start from and how it should looks like.

Comment: Yesssssss... Thank you ^_^